# XHR is working fine but Fetch API causing CORS error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I am starting to build a Reactjs app that uses Fetch API for my requests to my Web API. I wasn't having any issues until I set up Microsoft authentication for my Azure application and now my requests throw a CORS error.

To troubleshoot where the issue might be, I set up the same request using XHR. I was able to complete the requests with no problem. I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me where I am going wrong?

**XHR Version**

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  
oReq.open('get', 'https://myazureapp.azurewebsites.net/api/user', true);  
oReq.send();
```

**Fetch API Version**

```
fetch('https://myazureapp.azurewebsites.net/api/user');
```

Here is my error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'https://myazureapp.azurewebsites.net' is therefore
not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Any insight on what I might be doing wrong would be great. Please let me know if you need any more information, and I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Fetch support can be iffy, check caniuse.com also not really an answer to your question but I highly suggest using axios for handling ajax in a react app

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak - I will take a look at caniuse.com. I am definitely open to other solutions. How come you would recommend axios?

Comment: It's a lot like fetch (promise based) but you don't need to worry about polyfills or browser support. I've also heard good things about superagent but I've never used it. https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

Comment: if you wanna stick with fetch though you might need to send some additional headers with your response, check the msdn docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak - Thank you. Looks like I have some reading to do!

Comment: Fetch doesn't send cookies in its default configuration.